# Datatables, add only id row to all columns link

Tags: datatables, href, rowid

I'm trying to create columns table that contain links with the row id (pk)
With the following code all the columns contain the link relative at column's data
    "columnDefs": [

```
    {
        targets:  "_all" ,
        render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
            if(type === 'display'){

                data = '<a href="/mytestid/' + encodeURIComponent(data) + '">' + data + '</a>';
            }

            return data;
        }
    }
],
```

modifying it with the following:

```
data = '<a href="/mytest/' + data.id + '">' + data + '</a>';
```

it returns '/mytestid/undefined'

Comment: have you tried adding property `rowid` too in your datatable initialization?   `rowId: 'nameOfColumnId'`

Comment: I solved simply with: data = '<a href="/mytest/' + encodeURIComponent(row[0]) + '">' + data + '</a>'; and I added the .hidden class to the first column (I don't need it)